# How to create a fiber using 'method' instead of a code block

Tags: ruby, fiber

Instead of doing this,

```
@fiber = Fiber.new do
  # ...
end
```

I am trying to do something like this:

```
def test
  yield
  # ...
end

def create(process)
  @fiber = Fiber.new(process)
end

create(method(:test))
```

How can I make the `Fiber` code look like the completed part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just convert the method to block:

```
def test
  Fiber.yield 2.71
  Fiber.yield 3.14
  Fiber.yield 42
end

def create(&process)
  @fiber = Fiber.new(&process)
end

create(&method(:test))

@fiber.resume # => 2.71
@fiber.resume # => 3.14
@fiber.resume # => 42
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that it can also be invoked via `create { test }`.